# Combining makefile and setup.py

Tags: makefile, setup.py

I usually write a makefile with an `install` target so that one can build and install with `make && make install`. This works for Shell and C projects. However, when I use Python, I usually write a `setup.py` to install the modules correctly.

In the makefile, I would like to call `./setup.py install`, I am not sure how to get all the parameters form the makefile, like `DESTDIR` right. Debian uses some special magic, when I package something with only a `setup.py` in it. Having a `makefile` present uses makefile magic.

Or is it possible to call `rst2man` and `gzip` and install those files into `$(DESTDIR)/usr/share/man` from `setup.py`? Then I could put everything into the `setup.py`.

How do I combine the two?

Comment: How do you get the parameters like `DESTDIR` right, when you run `setup.py` without Make?

Comment: `debuild` magic does that for me.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `setup.py` installs modules into `sys.prefix` (you can have different Pythons with different `sys.prefix`).

You can override that with `--prefix` argument to `setup.py`.

E.g.:

```
build :
    cd module && CPPFLAGS=${CPPFLAGS} python setup.py build --prefix=${PREFIX}

install :
    cd module && CPPFLAGS=${CPPFLAGS} python setup.py install --prefix=${PREFIX}
```

See [How installation works](http://docs.python.org/2/install/#how-installation-works) for more details.

Comment: The thing is that on Debian one would need to set the layout to `deb`, whereas I think that should not be set in the upstream sources.

Comment: @queueoverflow I am not familiar with Debian. My point is that you have control over installation paths and build flags. I build my own Python stack from scratch using GNU make and this is how I build and install modules.